# How to notify REST API clients for an optional/required update?

Tags: http, rest, version, deprecated

I'm currently developing a Restful API and I'm wondering what would the most elegant, long lived solution.

Some data:

- The Rest API: server backend
- The application: mobile application (ios, android, etc.)

Both are managed and consumed by us.

Here is my requirements:

1. An update is optional but recommended, we just want to notify the client to update his application.
2. An update is required and the API is no longer usable (this should never happens because of the api versioning but who knows)

I can think of several solution:

- Include a new HTTP header, something like:

`X-Client-Update: text="Some informative and meaningful message"; button="Do upgrade now!"; uri="itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/DevelopmentCompanyLLC"`

The application will be in charge to process it and display it to the user.

- Provide an endpoint:

Request:

```
POST /api/versions/
Content-Type: application/json
{"client_version": "4.3", "os_version": "6.0", "os_vendor": "ios"}
```

Response (update available):

```
{
    "current_version": "4.4", 
    "latest_compatible_version": "4.0",
    "update_required": false,
    "update_available": true,
    "message": "A new awesome update is available, download it now",
    "uri": "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/DevelopmentCompanyLLC",
    "button_text": "I want it, and I want it now!"
}
```

Response (no update available):

```
{
    "current_version": "4.3", 
    "latest_compatible_version": "4.0",
    "update_required": false,
    "update_available": false,
}
```

In case where an application update is **required** I also want to always return an error which will be handled by the application.

I'm wondering which HTTP status I should use, for now I think of `400 Bad parameters` because I couldn't find any better code.

The according message would be very similar to the one provided by the endpoint solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the server and the client are both being developed by you, it's not so much important which status code to use (imho). In addition to `400` which is your selection, you may also look at the following status codes:

- `403` Forbidden - is appropriate if *the server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it; the server should describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.*
- `501` Not Implemented - is appropriate if *the server does not support [anymore] the functionality required to fulfill the request*.

As you wrote that required update should never happen normally, and so optional update is the main use case, the conditional response for latter seemingly fits into any successfull request. In this case you should possibly use `200` status code as usual, and rely on the additional headers in the reponse.

Comment: They are actually developed by us, but we intend to provide a public endpoint for some our partners, then it is a bit biased. I though of the `403 Forbidden` but it is likely understood as an Authorization problem, the `500` range defines servers errors, it is a pov, but I'm wondering if it is a server problem if the client is deprecated : )

Comment: Well, I also think 5XX errors are semantically server-oriented. But if a client calls unsupported method (which is not limited to the case the method was supported in past) shouldn't this become a 501 error on server? I think this is a matter of personal interpretation. It's up to you to decide. ;-) As for 403, [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says "Authorization **will not** help". There is `401` for authorization problems.